# Вывод построчно в jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Добрый день помогите пожалуйста решить две проблемы в этом моем коде:

1)Как сделать чтобы значения выводились построчно?

2)И как добавить подписи?

**Вот исходный код  и вывод**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
%matplotlib inline 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
import numpy as np
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


file = r"C:\DS\Sberbank_5.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";")
#print(df.head(5))

df.raznica = df["<CLOSE>"] - df["<OPEN>"]
d = [i for i in df.raznica]
o = [i for i in df["<OPEN>"]]
c = [i for i in df["<CLOSE>"]]
v = [i for i in df["<VOL>"]]

def ind(q, w, e):

    ind_bull_pogl = []
    ind_bear_pogl = []
    k = 1

    for i in range(len(d) - 20):
        if (d[i] < 0) and (d[i+1] < 0) and (d[i+2] < 0) and (d[i+3] > 0) and ((abs(d[i+3])/abs(d[i+2])) > q) and (((abs(d[i+2])*100)/o[i+2]) > w) and ((((o[i] - c[i+2])*100)/c[i+2]) > e):
            ind_bull_pogl.append(i+3)    
    for i in range(len(d) - 20):
        if (d[i] > 0) and (d[i+1] > 0) and (d[i+2] > 0) and (d[i+3] < 0) and ((abs(d[i+3])/abs(d[i+2])) > q) and (((abs(d[i+2])*100)/o[i+2]) > w) and ((((c[i+2] - o[i])*100)/c[i+2]) > e):
            ind_bear_pogl.append(i+3)
            
    profit_bull = [c[i + k] - c[i] for i in ind_bull_pogl]    
    profit_bear = [c[i] - c[i + k] for i in ind_bear_pogl]
    
    summa = sum(profit_bull) + sum(profit_bear)
    
    return summa, len(profit_bull), len(profit_bear)

q = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2. , 2.1, 2.2, 2.3,
        2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3. , 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6,
        3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4. ]
w = [0.05, 0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 ]
e = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ]

pb_dict = {}

for i in q:
    for ii in w:
        for iii in e:
            pb_dict[i, ii, iii]=ind(i, ii, iii)
        

pb_Dict = [(k, pb_dict[k]) for k in sorted(pb_dict, key=pb_dict.get, reverse=True)]
print(pb_Dict[0: 25])
```

**Хочу получить следующий вывод**

То, как на картинке это такой вывод я хочу получить (клепал в пэинте)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не "клепайте в пэинте", добавляйте код текстом: людям для ответа на вопрос не придется перенабирать

Comment: Извините, вы правы. Сейчас исправлю. @Jack_oS

Comment: NameError: name 'ind' is not defined

Comment: что за "ind" в коде?

Comment: И ещё не очень понятно, зачем вы в переменную где был словарь потом записываете список. Это чтобы всех запутать?

Comment: Попробуйте в последней строке кода просто `print` убрать, оставить только `pb_Dict[0: 25]`.

Comment: ind - функция, вставил весь код @Jack_oS

Comment: @CrazyElf вставил весь код. Пытаюсь оптимизацию функции сделать

Comment: @insolor Первый вопрос решился спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
for el in pb_Dict[0: 25]:
    print(el)
```

либо так:

```
print(*pb_Dict[0: 25], sep = "\n")
```